# login failed with correct password in django

Tags: django

I got an error in Django (3.1.7) when trying to login but superuser can login with this form

Here is code

I used builtin signup and login from and just add form-control classes in both forms

form.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm, UsernameField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _

class UsersignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password_again = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id','username','first_name','last_name','email']
        widgets = {
            'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','autocomplete':'off'}),
            'first_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','autocomplete':'off'}),
            'last_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','autocomplete':'off'}),
            'email':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','autocomplete':'off'}),
        }

class UserloginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = UsernameField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','autofocus':True,'autocomplete':'off'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label=_('password'), strip=False, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','autofocus':True}))
```

veiws.py

Here to login first use authenticate function and then used login function. In think authenticate function is not work

```
from .forms import UsersignupForm, UserloginForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, logout, login

#Signup View
def user_signup(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UsersignupForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
        else:
            form = UsersignupForm()
        return render(request, 'blogapp/signup.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')


#Login View
def user_login(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserloginForm(data=request.POST, request=request)
            if form.is_valid():
                usm = form.cleaned_data['username']
                psw = form.cleaned_data['password']
                user = authenticate(username=usm, password=psw)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
        else:
            form = UserloginForm()
        return render(request, 'blogapp/login.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
```

Error in terminal

In terminal I got this in browser 'Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.' this error rise

```
[14/Mar/2021 17:56:11] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3225
[14/Mar/2021 17:56:11] "GET /static/blogapp/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[14/Mar/2021 17:56:11] "GET /static/blogapp/images/first.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[14/Mar/2021 17:56:11] "GET /static/blogapp/images/second.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[14/Mar/2021 17:56:11] "GET /static/blogapp/images/third.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[14/Mar/2021 17:56:13] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3659
[14/Mar/2021 17:56:21] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3853
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add code / errors as text formatted as code not images. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: How did you *register* the user?

Comment: using UserCereationForm

Comment: @oliverqueen please [edit] your question. Remove those images and add actual code. Also add how you register your users. (If you don't know how to format code just paste it in someone would edit it for you).

Comment: Include both the views where you create a user, and where you authenticate a user.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you directly create a form of your own for creating a user. That too is fine but the problem is that this form does not know that creating a user instance requires an extra step of setting the password. This is so because the password is not stored as plain text in the database but as a hash.

Instead of inheriting from `forms.ModelForm` your form should inherit from `UserCreationForm`: which would perform this step for you:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class UsersignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    # UserCreationForm has two fields `password1` and `password2` so removed yours
    
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ['id','username','first_name','last_name','email']
        widgets = {
            'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','autocomplete':'off'}),
            'first_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','autocomplete':'off'}),
            'last_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','autocomplete':'off'}),
            'email':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','autocomplete':'off'}),
        }
```

> **Note**: Either delete your previously created users or set their password from the admin site.